# Wordpress plugin WP Oauth endpoint /oauth/authorize? return a blank reponse

Tags: wordpress, oauth

I have created my client, checked the “Authorisation code” as allowed grant type.

In settings, the “Enable OAuth Server” is checked.

curl -X GET ‘https://www.example.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXX&response_type=code

It returns absolutely nothing, just blank body. I got the same with response with Postman.

With Chrome, I’m just redirected to the redirected URI I have setup in the client settings.

Any idea?

I have posted a question on the support page of their plugin but it seems they did not reply to any support issues since one month ...

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/endpoint-oauth-authorize-return-nothing

Comment: What is the response status code and headers that you get in curl/postman? Very often a response to the authorization endpoint would be a redirect. Maybe you're not following the redirects?

Comment: And check error logs as well.